# Why are the onStart and onResume methods for a Fragment called even though the fragment is not in the foreground

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using a `ViewPager` inside a `TabLayout`. The `ViewPager` has 3 pages where each page is a fragment.
When the activity containing the `TabLayout` starts, the fragment callback methods upto onResume() are called for fragment1, which is as expected and fragment1 is displayed on the screen.

However, `logcat` shows that the callback methods upto `onResume` are also called for fragment2, although fragment2 is currently not being displayed on the screen. This looks odd to me since `onResume` should only be called when a fragment is about to become visible.

When I select fragment2, `onResume` is called for fragment3, although fragment3 is not being displayed. So there seems to be a pattern to this behaviour.

What could be the cause for this?

Update: The `ViewPager` I am using is a subclass of `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Comment: I am using  subclass of `FragmentPagerAdapter`. But, no matter which adapter I use, how is it possible that `onResume` is called when the fragment is not visible on the screen. Doesn't this violate the meaning of `onResume`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things contribute to this behavior:

1. Fragments are not required to have a UI, in which case it is never "visible" on screen. Basically, if a Fragment is attached to an Activity, its lifecycle methods will be called as appropriate.
2. ViewPager loads items to either side of the item that is currently displayed. This is in order to have content to show as the user scrolls the page with his finger. By default the off screen page limit is 1, which means that when your first fragment is the current item, the second fragment is loaded off screen in preparation for scrolling.

You can always check which item is displayed by the ViewPager using `getCurrentItem()`. If you are having problems because the fragment are destroyed and recreated needlessly when they go beyond the off screen page limit, you can increase the page limit with `setOffscreenPageLimit()`.

Answer (score 3):

If is default behavior of `ViewPager` to call next `Fragment` when `ViewPager` is initilized.

You need to use `setOffscreenPageLimit()`

`setOffscreenPageLimit()` sets the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page

`Default value` is `1` so next `Fragment` to the left and to the right will stay in memory.

To prevent from calling next `Fragment` you need to set `0` value to  `OffscreenPageLimit`

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
```

on the `ViewPager` object.

**EDIT:**

But i have checked by setting limit to `0`.

`setOffscreenPageLimit(0)` will not work now. when you set limit to `0` you can see below warning in `LogCat`:

```
Requested offscreen page limit 0 too small; defaulting to 1
```

So i advise you to either call `setOffscreenPageLimit(2)` which will keep all your 3 Fragments in memory otherwise don't call `setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)` on ViewPager.